# Dynamically change parameter with js and three.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, three.js

I have a problem as I'm not a pro in js. I want to change dynamically the parameter passed to a function written in javascript, but it is written with a "style" that i don't understand, so I'm looking for an help.

I have a page where you can set some parameter of a scene, then i get the value of each of them with the function "reload()", but I don't know how to pass them to the function that next will render the scene.

Three.js uses some function, I'm actually able to render the scene but I can't pass the parameters as the function is written this way: (example that I got from internet)

```
var lesson6 = {
scene: null,
camera: null,
renderer: null,
container: null,
controls: null,
clock: null,
stats: null,

init: function() { // Initialization

// create main scene
this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( '0x'+sfondo_scena );
//REST OF CODE
```

in this code for example i don't know how to pass the value of "sfondo_scena".

the test page that i'm using is hosted here (very small code)  [Link](http://jaaxlab.com/test_youring/index1.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding a parameter (I called it `value`) to the `init` function ...

```
init: function(value) { // Initialization
```

... and then calling it with the value of the input?

```
var sfondo_scena = $("#sfondo-scena");
// Other code omitted
lesson6.init(sfondo_scena.val());
```

Comment: It won't work...i hosted the page with the code modified as you said if you want to see..i'm not sure I've done it right

Comment: It doesn't work because Three.js can't parse the color. Try `var support = '#'+sfondo_scena` instead of  `var support = '0x'+sfondo_scena`.